# Blog.xsl File Request

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365

I am trying to modify the view from of a default blog. Our company requires to brand the look and feel. I have found several good resources online and they all involve modifying `blog.xsl`.

This is usually found in `program files/common files/microsoft shared/web server extensions/14/template/layouts/xsl`

My issue is that we are on SharePoint Online, so we do not have access to this file. Now, I know that via the blog webpart on `Posts.aspx`, I can set it to use another XSL. My issue is that I do not have the 2013 `blog.xsl` to start with.

Is there a gentle soul out there to please make it available for download?

Comment: I'd love to know this as well, if anybody has any ideas?

Comment: I ultimately had to go to a demo onsite install and grab it from there.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent URL in SharePoint Online (Office 365) would be

```
<siteCollectionURL>/_layouts/xsl/blog.xsl
```

as in

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MyBlog/_layouts/xsl/blog.xsl
```

---

A standard blog.xsl file is publicly available in my dropbox on URL https://www.dropbox.com/s/iav276drxv9rqdz/blog.xsl?dl=0